# Mongoose-Unique-Validator giving unique error when trying to update a field (MongoDB/JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a blog application using `MongoDB/Mongoose` on an `Express` server. I am using `Mongoose-Unique-Validator`.

Each user document has a `posts` field which is an array consisting of post ID's.
When a user makes a new post, I attempt to update their document to add the post to their posts array:

```
let user = await User.findById("61b45baa09caf8ee462248df")
    await post.save().then(savedPost => {
        user.posts = user.posts.concat(savedPost.id)
        user.save()
    })
```

When this code is run, the following error is outputted:

```
  errors: {
    _id: ValidatorError: Error, expected `_id` to be unique. Value: `61b45baa09caf8ee462248df`
        at validate (C:\Users\avery\Desktop\blog\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1277:13)
        at C:\Users\avery\Desktop\blog\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1252:24
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
      properties: [Object],
      kind: 'unique',
      path: '_id',
      value: new ObjectId("61b45baa09caf8ee462248df"),
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    }
  },
  _message: 'User validation failed'
```

My `userSchema` is as follows::

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator')

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    passwordHash: String,
    posts: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:'Post'
        }
    ]
})

userSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator)

userSchema.set('toJSON', {
    transform: (document, returnedObject) => {
        returnedObject.id = returnedObject._id.toString()
        delete returnedObject._id
        delete returnedObject.__v
        delete returnedObject.passwordHash
    }
})

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)

module.exports = User
```

What the issue is here?

Answer (score -1):

This issue is already mentioned on its github repository. this may help.[Mentioned in official Github of Plugin](https://github.com/blakehaswell/mongoose-unique-validator/issues/110)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).